# Failed to send request to error with Data Loader Log In

Tags: data-loader, login, username

I am getting the following error when I am trying to log into Data Loader:

> Failed to send request to

I checked that I am providing the correct `Username`, and the correct `Password` (in the form of password + Security token).

So, what else may be wrong here?

[image]

After changing the `Salesforce Login URL` here is what I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***Password*** should be a combination of **Password + Security Token** if you do not have IP Whitelisting done.

Also, if you are connecting to a Production / Developer instance, the url `https://login.salesforce.com` is valid.

If it is a Sandbox that you are trying to connect to the then the url should be `https://test.salesforce.com`

Comment: Lol, I tried the same solution and it did not help. But it worked when I tried it after your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing data loader settings once as below:
Open Data Loader -> At the top click on settings -> Set the server host to https://login.salesforce.com -> ok
Then try logging in.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the VPN. Salesforce suggests in the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324395&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) to update proxy settings in Data Loader > Settings > Proxy Host / Port.

> 3. Check if your network is using a proxy - Getting the error message, "Failed to send request to
>    [https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/31.0"](https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/31.0%22) typically indicates
>    that you're going through a proxy server resulting in your login
>    attempt from the Data Loader not making it from your local machine to
>    Salesforce servers. If your network is utilizing a VPN, you'll need to
>    include or set your proxy information in the Data Loader settings. We
>    recommend contacting your IT department to get the following pieces of
>    information:
>
> - Proxy host
> - Proxy port
> - Proxy username
> - Proxy password settings